# Info basics: where is package Info?

Tags: package, help, info

I just grabbed `csv` from elpa (melpa) and, of course, the install buffer had the blurb about `csv`. I take it that blurb is an Info file somewhere? Or is it just a section of the `csv.el` comments? In other words, where can I access these usage instructions once I've installed `csv`?

Investigating, I did `C-h v` for `Info-directory-list` which I assume will give me a list of all the Info files' directories? This is what came up:

```
("/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-12.1.0" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/ebib-20180111.30" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/ess-20180123.1313" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/geiser-20171217.1353" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/haskell-mode-20171022.26" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-90150116" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20180122" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/ivy-20180115.1555" "/home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20180122" "/usr/local/share/info/" "/usr/share/info/" "/usr/local/share/info/")
```

It says this variable `Info-directory-list` is defined in `info.el,` but then where do these specific directory listings that appear in the list form above reside? They're not in my `init.el`.

Comment: (describe-variable 'Info-directory-list): Documentation:
List of directories to search for Info documentation files.
If nil, meaning not yet initialized, Info uses the environment
variable INFOPATH to initialize it, or ‘Info-default-directory-list’
if there is no INFOPATH variable in the environment, or the
concatenation of the two if INFOPATH ends with a ‘path-separator’.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's increasingly common for packages not to include info files (including mine!). The blurb you see in the package-list is, I think, something submitted to the MELPA repository when the package is added. For packages like csv, that don't include help files, you can check the help for the mode, e.g., `C-h f csv-mode`, or try `M-x find-library csv-mode` and read the comments at the top of the file.

Comment: Use `M-x finder-commentary` to read the Commentary of a Lisp file. You enter any file name suitable for passing to `locate-library`.

Comment: I just customized `Info-additional-directory-list` and it placed the directory I gave it in my `init.el` file: `(custom-set-variables . . . '(Info-additional-directory-list (quote ("/home/me/myinfo")))` but where are the others kept. I have no `INFOPATH` set up as far as I know. In the OP I listed the results of `C-h v Info-directory-list`. So where, how is it getting this information?

Comment: package.el adds the ones it found. The others look like default paths which emacs probably figures out as standard behaviour.

Comment: So this get populated by calling a function in `package.el`. Okay. Now, in general is there a way to find out what code populates a given variable?

Comment: In emacs 26 see `C-h f debug-on-variable-change`